# Avoiding ground currents through metal enclosures on communal conductors

Tags: grounding

I share a metal fence with my neighbor. I would like to secure a metal lamp enclosure to it. NEC generally calls for metal enclosures to be Ground-bonded. How do I avoid creating hazardous ground currents when I secure my metal enclosure to the common metal fence?

The problem is that if my neighbor and I both secure electrical boxes to the fence in a way that connects our grounds together, then a return current path is created, as shown by the arrow marked "!" in the following drawing.

[image]

These ground currents create multiple potential hazards. For instance:

1. Current is now carried through grounds *inside* each building, creating voltages where they're not expected.
2. In some instances of this problem, the fence segment is potentially thicker and/or shorter than the utility wiring, making the fence the path of lowest resistance. The lamp enclosure is bonded through a 14AWG conductor that could then be roasted by 100A return currents from loads in building 2.

What is the general practice for avoiding these potential safety hazards?

Comment: Use a grounding rod, not a metal fence.

Comment: @Math Keeps Me Busy *Use a grounding rod, not a metal fence.* Right, the question is how to do that, when the metal fence is a necessary mechanical support. Each main panel has a grounding rod, per code (of course, the grounding rods required for an ordinary main panel are not particularly conductive to earth... the requirement for one is 25 ohms, and even worse if you have 2 or more). The question is how to use the shared fence as a *mechanical* support without creating electrical hazards.

Comment: The steel fence almost certainly has much higher resistance than the copper house wiring. Steel has a resistivity about 10 times that of copper. Even if ground currents did flow - the voltages would be very low and not cause a problem.

Comment: @Kevin *Steel has a resistivity about 10 times that of copper.* That's a good point. Note however that local utility wiring in my area is generally aluminum, and a fence might be aluminum too -- with a much higher cross section. I thought the idea of electric codes is to standardize practices that work in all reasonable situations. Therefore, wouldn't standard practice accomodate all of these cases, as well as boxes fed by two buildings simply being mounted right next to each other? For example, my neighbor and I want to put lights on the same post, facing in different directions?